# Normal laboratory values for tests from the hospital/medical centers contributing to MIMIC database

Tags: mimic-iii

Where can I get laboratory normal values and ranges for laboratory tests in the MIMIC database - tests like hematocrit, red blood cell count, bicarbonate, blood urea nitrogen, etc.?

Specifically from the hospitals associated with the database. I have data from [Texas Tech University Health Sciences Center El Paso](http://www.msdmanuals.com/professional/appendixes/normal-laboratory-values/normal-laboratory-values) and there, like almost anywhere else where  normal values are published, there is the qualification

> Note: The reference values provided in these tables should be used as guidelines only. Reference values vary based on several factors, including the demographics of the healthy population from which specimens were obtained and the specific methods and/or instruments used to assay these specimens.
>
> Laboratories that are accredited by the College of American Pathologists (CAP) are required to establish and/or validate their own reference values at least annually. Thus, any given result should be interpreted based on the reference value of the laboratory in which the test was done; the laboratory typically provides these values with the test result.

I am noting discrepancies in normal ranges and mean ranges from the MIMIC database for some of the laboratory tests, in particular hematocrit, hemoglobin, red blood cell count and blood urea nitrogen (BUN), while the majority of the tests like sodium, potassium, etc fall within accepted normal ranges.

Answer (score 0):

The reference ranges will be included in a future release of MIMIC.

You can get an approximation by looking up the LOINC code associated with each lab in the labevents table. LOINC codes are often associated with reference ranges specific to the test performed.

Comment: I agree that the answer is unsatisfying, but it's the answer.

Comment: Do you have a reference, an authoritative source? That would make it a good answer.

Comment: That would be great. When will that release happen? Is it possible to send me those in advance? My email is david_ross@curvmed.com. Much appreciated. In addition to those discrepancies I mentioned, are central venous pressure and the three PAPs. Note, my dataset I am working on is the MetaVision source of MIMIC-iii and I have included data from the Waveforms (matched) Database.

Comment: There are >1500 labs with many changes over the last decade so preparing a custom extract would be very time consuming. I updated my answer as you could reference the LOINC codes in the labevents table and it may give further insight.